# mystery "welcome" app from web2py on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I'm deploying, for the first time, an app on google app engine.

It seems to have succeeded, however when I go to my apps url I'm directed to the traditional "welcome" page from the default installation.

I do not have a "welcome" app.  nothing about "welcome" is listed in my routes.py file.

so why am I directed to myURL/welcome/default/index  ?

I can't even type in the direct url that I know I want to access without an "invalid request" error.

This also only happens when I upload and run from appspot.com, when I use the local development engine things are fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Dispatching) rules, if you go to a URL without specifying an application, it will default to the `init` application, and if not found, it will then look for the `welcome` application. Also, if you used the standard `app.example.yaml` configuration file when deploying, the `welcome` application would have been included in your deployment (see the [GAE deployment](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13#Configuration) section of the book).

Comment: I See.  I had deleted it from my app.yaml so I was very confused as to where it was coming from.  Still doesn't quite explain to me though why I don't have a problem when I test locally, but as soon as it's uploaded there is a failure.  I might expect a database error on my end or something but not simply loading a static page.

Comment: I couple things I'm confused by is that in the GAE deployment it says that an index.yaml file will be generated.  But I don't see that happening.  Even if it was, it is listed among the items to skip.  So how does GAE actually make use of it?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to delete the `welcome` app from the app.yaml file? Both locally and on GAE, what URL are you using to get to your app?

Comment: Regarding the index.yaml file, are you running the app locally using the GAE appserver? Note, index.yaml is excluded in the app.yaml file because the configuration files are sent to the server separately (see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Skipping_Files)).

Comment: sorry I misspoke. I meant that I had deleted the welcome app.  I did not change the app.yaml file to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

not much of an answer, because I still don't know exactly how the routing occurred, however I had the web2py app in 2 locations.  On my local machine and on the web hosting server.  I had been uploading the version from the hosting server to GAE.  This one was failing.  When I uploaded the one from my local machine things started to work.

So I must have had a discrepancy somewhere between the two I just couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

You must call your application: "init" and deploy it in GAE.

For example, if you have developed `yourweb2pyapp`, your main page will be `yourweb2pyapp/default/index` and your main page in GAE would be `yourGAEapp.appspot.com/yourweb2pyapp/default/index`.

But if you write in your browser `yourGAEapp.appspot.com` you go to `yourGAEapp.appspot.com/welcome/default/index` and this is the problem.

The simplest solution is that you call your application "init" instead of `yourweb2pyapp` when you deploy it in GAE. So you new main, and default page will be `yourGAEapp.appspot.com/init/default/index`

You can pack `yourweb2pyapp` and then import it as `init.`

You have to be careful with the internal links.